# Using a data set collected against the terms of service of a company?

Tags: research-process

Many entities (companies, websites) clearly state on their terms of service that data collection is not allowed. For example many websites don't allow scraping.

I plan to collect data and then publish a paper using them. I will state how I collected them.

Can my paper be denied if I do the above?

Note: This is not about possible legal consequences. I am simply asking if my paper will be published or not.

Comment: This is a legal question, and we are not lawyers (okay, most of us). I recommend running this by your school's legal counsel first.

Comment: That is an interesting question if we extend it to data that entities behind websites do not want us to collect. For instance, public transportation companies are not happy about users scraping their websites to extract timetable information, and even less so when it comes to data about delays.

Comment: @tonysdg I am not interested in the legal aspect. I don't think (care if) I will be sued. I am interested for my paper to be accepted.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper valid point

Comment: @NET_GUY Then I'd say this is a question for the editor of whatever journal/conference/book you have in mind ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most serious organizations (journals, conferences, etc) have standards of ethics they abide by, and individual peer reviewers also have their own standards of research ethics. In some fields these are very explicit and written out at length, such as with the American Psychological Association (APA) or [the Association of Computing Machinery (ACM)](https://www.acm.org/about-acm/acm-code-of-ethics-and-professional-conduct).

When submitting to a venue, there is almost always some statement of ethical/legal compliance which you must agree to. As such, violating any aspect of the codes, ethics, or legal principles the organization (or editors, or reviewers) value is absolutely grounds for rejection of a paper, or retraction if violation is discovered later. The editor is fully within their rights to reject a paper that violates any of their standards, and the individual reviewers are free to suggest the paper be rejected on any such grounds.

Various people and organizations value things differently, so some venues might be more comfortable with some types of violations than others. Some might be OK with violating a terms of service to scrape data, while some others might be happy to reject you outright for such a practice. I'm certain this area is also changing and evolving quite rapidly, so even venues that previously published similar papers might no longer be interested in such methods. Some will even way your methods against the outcomes, and if the research is interesting enough they'll look past the other failings - and some just don't care at all; your research could have been about electrocuting kittens to see how loud they cry and they'd publish it just the same.

I would encourage you to think more long-term than whether or not a paper gets accepted, however. A single accepted paper which shows a researcher to be dangerously negligent, in terms of legal responsibility or ethical guidelines, can quickly find themselves considered a liability to future collaborators, advisers, and employers. Academia heavily relies on reputation, and a reputation of taking short-cuts, ignoring ethical guidelines, and not caring whether what they do is illegal or could result in losing lawsuits...I don't know whether such a reputation will open the kinds of doors you'd be happy to walk through.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! To be honest, all I am going to do is scrape a few pages from a site. While this is against their TOS, it's not something terribly "unethical". But I see your point.

Comment: Venues do differ **a lot**.  Information security papers that deal with operating systems almost always breach the ToS of the system they're breaking into.  The prime example is probably the Evil Maid Attack paper (actually papers) which defies the non-tinkering rule in the Apple's OSX ToS.

Comment: @NET_GUY It's a bit separate from the question issue itself of obtaining the data, but I should also warn that it also depends on what the data actually is. If it was, for instance, profiles from a dating website, or otherwise data from/about individual people, then that's a completely new can of worms as (again which depends on your field) may require IRB approval. Potentially personally identifying data requires a whole new set of care and ethics beyond, say, scraping stock data.